# logger with file name, line and time stamp

Tags: c++, logging

I have a custom logger class with different methods for debug, info, etc. messages. Beside the log message, I would like to print also the name and line of the file from which the logger method is called, as well as the timestamp.

The solution I have now is something like this:

```
m_logger.debug("some debug message", __FILE__ , __LINE__, __TIME__);
```

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid the call of the two macros `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__TIME__` and implement that somewho such that it is called automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#define debug_with_ft(x) debug(x, __FILE__, __TIME__)

...
m_logger.debug_with_ft("some debug message");
```

Of course, there are various different ways to solve this, e.g. hide the entire `m_logger` in the macros:

```
#define debug_with_ft(x) m_logger.debug(x, __FILE__, __TIME__)
```

Comment: as Laurent stated, this is not a solution for `__TIME__`. Although for `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` this seems to be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ezdazuzena: That is a solution for automatically calling any or all of `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` **and** `__TIME__`. The problem that `__TIME__` is not what you really want, but that would be a completely separate question. One you didn't ask.

Comment: It will work but I think using hard coded macro magic will get one into troubles sooner than later. It's gonna be quite a PIA when the call signature will change, or the name of the method, or anything about it.

Comment: Well, I can't know that when you ask for __TIME__ you actualy mean something completely different than __TIME__, can I? Clearly, you could add a timestamp too, either as part of the `debug()` member function of your logging class, or in a macro, it that's what you want. You may have to write a function that calls some function to figure out what time it is and format the time into something you can print. But it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 4):

`__TIME__` is a preprocessor macro that will produce the current time **at compile time**. Thus it should not be used in your case because you probably want to access current time **at runtime** (when the message is logged).

`__FILE__` is also a preprocessor macro and must be evaluated at pre-compilation time, you cannot implement it in another way.

You may also be interested by the `__LINE__` macro

Comment: Thanks, I actually forgot the `__LINE__ macro.

Answer (score 2):

This is one case where macros *are* the correct solution.  You
want to invoke your logger using a macro (since only a macro can
automatically insert `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`), and you want to
do so in a way that allows the client code to pass one or more
message elements, probably using `<<`.  The usual way of doing
this is something like:

```
#define LOG() m_logger.getStream( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

, where `m_logger.getStream` inserts the header (using its 
arguments and the current time), and returns either a reference
to the log stream, or a special wrapper class which also
implements `<<`—Just returning a reference to the stream is
the easiest, but using a wrapper allows catching the end of the
message (because the wrapper is a temporary, which will be
destructed at the end of the full expression), to free a lock
taken in `getStream` (so that logging is thread safe), or to
ensure that the output is atomic, and if the `<<` wrapper is
something like:

```
template <typename T>
LogStream& LogStream::operator<<( T const& object )
{
    if ( myStream != NULL ) {
        *myStream << object;
    }
}
```

, you can disable logging, and will not do any conversions if
it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you consider `__FILE__` and `__TIME__` are bad ? I am not sure if they are really macros per-se. They are so-called *macro-names*. I also think they are defined by standard, so it should be safe and ok to use them.

On the side note you seem to miss the concept of compile-time evaulation and run-time evaulation.

How would you know the name of the source file during run-time ? That is why you should use `__FILE__` as the compiler will evaluate the file name for you.

On the contrary `__TIME__` is also macro name replaced by compiler. Do you want to log the time at which the line was compiled or called ? If it is the latter you should use appropriate run-time functions.

I don't think there is any possibility to go around `__FILE__`.

**However, if you want just to shorten the call**

I use following snippet:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg) do{ std::cerr << __FILE__ << "(@" << __LINE__ << "): " << msg << '\n'; } while( false )
#else
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg) do{ } while ( false )
#endif
```

I find it quite portable and easy to use, but it's not meant to be used as a class method.
You could probably define it as something like

```
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg) debug( msg, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

and use like

```
m_logger.DEBUG_MSG("message");
```

so the macro would expand to the designed function call. However it is quite risky.
If you change `debug` signature you need to change macro, and its hardly portable.